# How any web hosting site protect files from deleting?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, shutil

I am creating a python code testing (pytest) website using django and deploy on azure and I just test a code and try to delete files in the root directory of my project using `shutil.rmtree()` but It returns code like this

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.7, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /tmp/8da77f5e80b846d
collected 1 item

codes/test_with_pytest.py F                                              [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_______________________________ test_check_test ________________________________

    def test_check_test():
        from .code import check_test
>       assert check_test() == 90

/tmp/8da77f5e80b846d/codes/test_with_pytest.py:3: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/tmp/8da77f5e80b846d/codes/code.py:7: in check_test
    shutil.rmtree('/')
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:726: in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:663: in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:663: in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:663: in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:663: in _rmtree_safe_fd
    _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:683: in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

topfd = 15, path = '/usr/local/azure/certs'
onerror = .onerror at 0x7efce0496310>

    def _rmtree_safe_fd(topfd, path, onerror):
        try:
            with os.scandir(topfd) as scandir_it:
                entries = list(scandir_it)
        except OSError as err:
            err.filename = path
            onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
            return
        for entry in entries:
            fullname = os.path.join(path, entry.name)
            try:
                is_dir = entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False)
            except OSError:
                is_dir = False
            else:
                if is_dir:
                    try:
                        orig_st = entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False)
                        is_dir = stat.S_ISDIR(orig_st.st_mode)
                    except OSError:
                        onerror(os.lstat, fullname, sys.exc_info())
                        continue
            if is_dir:
                try:
                    dirfd = os.open(entry.name, os.O_RDONLY, dir_fd=topfd)
                except OSError:
                    onerror(os.open, fullname, sys.exc_info())
                else:
                    try:
                        if os.path.samestat(orig_st, os.fstat(dirfd)):
                            _rmtree_safe_fd(dirfd, fullname, onerror)
                            try:
                                os.rmdir(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
                            except OSError:
                                onerror(os.rmdir, fullname, sys.exc_info())
                        else:
                            try:
                                # This can only happen if someone replaces
                                # a directory with a symlink after the call to
                                # os.scandir or stat.S_ISDIR above.
                                raise OSError("Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic "
                                              "link")
                            except OSError:
                                onerror(os.path.islink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
                    finally:
                        os.close(dirfd)
            else:
                try:
>                   os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
E                   OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'Microsoft_Azure_TLS_Issuing_CA_01.crt'

/opt/python/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/shutil.py:681: OSError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
/tmp/8da77f5e80b846d
/
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED codes/test_with_pytest.py::test_check_test - OSError: [Errno 30] Read-...
============================== 1 failed in 0.45s ===============================
```

and it didn't delete a file.
Also, I interpreted os.chdir("..") and then tried to delete files this time code even don't run and give a server-side error. This error didn't solve by refreshing the page instead I had to restart azure server.

How Azure or any other web hosting platform protects files from getting deleted and if any file delete then which files may get deleted?

Comment: Simply, Azure has mounted the file system containing your code as read-only for your running webserver.  There are many ways your root directory *could* be be protected, and this is just one of them.  Why is it done?  To limit the ways that your site could be damaged if your webapp has security vulnerabilities.  (If a bad guy could inject code into your app due to some other vulnerability, then that code could basically add / modify / delete any file in the file system.  You ... and more important, your client ... don't want that.)

Comment: How is it done technically?  Well, certainly on Linux / Unix (and probably Windows too), mounting a file system as read-only is standard operating system functionality.   And you can't subvert a read-only mount from the application (e.g. web container / server or web app).  Or by changing file permissions, ACLS, etc.   So whatever problem you are trying to solve by writing files into the webapp code tree, you need to solve that problem some other way.

Comment: if I want to create a new mounted file system in my web app for different users then how could I do that using python. Like the same as azure do for their users that their users data is isolated.

Comment: Also what I do another thing is created a link which change directory `os.chdir(..)` when someone hit that link then some of the functionality not working. Is the python executing directory changed by this like the server works on temp/user123 should now the directory become temp only.

Comment: There are various ways to "solve" this (i.e. make Azure mount the filesystem as writable instead).  Google for `azure web app service "read only file system" site:stackoverflow.com`.   Whether this is a good thing to do?  I've already said whjy I think it is not; see above.   (And you didn't ask not to stop Azure doing this.  You asked how Azure does it.  That's a different question!)

Comment: For what it is worth, I doubt that either of your ideas will work.  1)  You can't mount the same file system twice (e.g. readonly and then read-write).  2) If the file is on a readonly file system its contents cannot be changed, *irrespective* the path you use to access it, or what the file permissions / ACLs say.  It is like the read-only mount stops you making any changes whatsoever to what has previously been written to the disk partition that holds the file system.